# WatchKit Page-based navigation willActivate called twice

Tags: objective-c, navigation, watchkit, apple-watch

I understand that willActivate is called on the next 'not displayed' view in order to allow it to prepare its content.

I need to know when a page is going to be displayed in order to send some information to the iPhone, and so I was simply ignoring the first `willActivate` call and on the second I 'know' it will be on screen.

However, if the user quickly flicks through the pages (just skipping the preloaded one is enough), `willActivate` is called only once and so my test doesn't work.

How can I accurately know when a page is going on-screen for sure (like `viewWillAppear:`), and has anyone achieved this?